# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'File': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am writing a JavaScript to write file to the local directory in an aframe virtual reality application using Google Chrome.

While debugging I've gotten this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'File': 2 arguments required, but `only 1 present.`
```

I've gotten the following code from someone else and I don't understand why Google Chrome says 2 arguments are required for this?

```
<script>
/// write to file
var txtFile = "skycolour.txt";
var file = new File(txtFile);
var str = "My string of text";

file.open("w"); // open file with write access
file.writeln("First line of text");
file.writeln("Second line of text " + str);
file.write(str);
file.close();
</script>
```

Thank you for helping out.

[Image of the error for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2a2o.jpg)

Comment: `var file = new File([""], txtFile);`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File